# Accessing other tabs/windows in a browser via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

I have a JavaScript application in a tab which opens if I click on a certain link on my page. If I click on the link again, I need to check if that tab is allready opened - if it is, then switch to that tab and do something, otherwise open a new tab.

Unfortunately using

```
var myApp = window.open("http://www.mypage.com/myapp.html", "My App");
if(myApp){
```

won't help me, because I can't rely on the URL, due to the fact that the URL will differ on each environment that I'm using.

How can I achieve this if I can't rely on the URL? The only thing I can check is the tab's name - it will allways be the same. How can I access the browser's tab array, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you cannot access the browser's tab array (certainly not through JavaScript).  This would be a security breach on the client side.  You should think of each browser tab as a browser instance of it's own - unaware of any other tab.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly how I'm thinking of it. However I need to ensure that the tab doesn't get opened multiple times. Can I ensure that in some way without knowing the exact URL?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The only way that you could do this would be to hold a flag on the launcher - but this is error prone.  How about using a popup ?

Comment: a separate popup as in *window.open()*? or a popup on the same page?

Comment: A javascript popup.  As an example, have a look at bootstrap modal dialogs : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 1):

You can track that if tab is opened already using the Cookie/Local storage.
Save the value `"isOpened=true"` in either Cookie or localStorage and Be sure to delete the values from the same when that tab is Closed or when user navigates to other pages using `"onunload"` event.

But the page you are going to open should be on the same Domain for accessing/ setting the Cookie.

Still we cannot do anything if the user opens the page by just copying the link.

Answer (score 0):

as you are opening new window using javascript you can do this
  you can add a dummy attribute say "data-isOpend='no'" on that element
and when user click on that element you can change that attribute to "data-isOpened='yes'"
and in javascript function before opening tha new window you have to check if data-isOpend=='no' then open link in new window else do nothing

Comment: This wouldn't work unfortunately. The `data-isOpened` attribute would be lost as soon as the client navigates from or reloads the page. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

(Just leaving a differenct ans here if any other dev comes here looking for solution for such prob,Just like me :) )

We can assign name to the tab while creating it 
 For eg.

```
function view_preview()
{
  var abc;
  if(abc!=null){
    abc.close();
  }
  var url=some_link
  abc=window.open(url,'tab_name');
}
```

Here, we are opening a new tab and if that tab is already opened we are 'refreshing' it.